# IIS Tomcate deployment error : Request Entity Too Large The page was not displayed because the request entity is too large

Tags: iis, deployment, tomcat9, isapi

I have the following configuration :

IIS v8.5 -> Tomcat9(IIS used as web server). I have ISAPI Connector installed with Tomcat in order to process requests. Everything works fine and I am able to launch my applications and access Tomcat Manager app.

However when I try to deploy large application ( > 220Mb ) through the Tomcat web interface ( Manager application ) I am getting this error :

```
HTTP Error 413.1 - Request Entity Too Large
The page was not displayed because the request entity is too large.
```

I updated IIS configuration :
IIS ->SystemWebServer.ServerRuntime.uploadReadAheadSize to 347483647 ~ 300MB, restarted IIS and Tomcat but it still didn't work and I got the same message as before.

I am able to deploy my application by dropping WAR file in $CATALINA_HOME/webapps

Comment: Please don't only set it in web.config, but also in applicationhost.config. By the way, set the <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="xxxx" executionTimeout="3600" /> and <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="xxxx" /> to larger.

Comment: I am not sure where to find applicationhost.config. Or should I update it via IIS application

Comment: You can find it through   %windir%\system32\inetsrv\config. You can update it via IIS, too.  Just click configuration editor at server level.